# How to add table when pressing a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-objects, dom-events

I am trying to make some kind of calendar where I can enter some tasks I already have the design template but I want to be able to add a new table (day) when I press a button.

[image]

In the image above you can see what I want to do.
This is the template I am using:

HTML

```
<tr>        
<th>            
<div class="dls">               
<div class="select">                    
<select name="dls" id="dls">                        
<option value="1" selected="selected">Monday</option>                       <option value="2">Tuesday</option>                      <option value="3">Wednesday</option>                        <option value="4">Thursday</option>                         <option value="5">Friday</option>                       <option value="6">Saturday</option>                         <option value="7">Sunday</option>                   
</select>               
</div>          
</div>      
</th>
</tr>

<tr>        
<td>            
<input type="text" name="publisher" form="pubName">             
<input type="text" name="publisher" form="pubName">             
<input type="text" name="publisher" form="pubName">             
<input type="text" name="publisher" form="pubName">         
</td> 
</tr>
```

CSS

```
body {  font-size: 13px; } 

.dls {  font-size: 13px;    text-align: center;     background: transparent;    border: none;   border-radius: 6px;     overflow: hidden;   position: relative; } 

.dls .select{   height: 22px;   width: 125px;   background-position: center;    text-align: center; } 

.dls .select select{    background: transparent;    line-height: 1;     border: 0;  padding: 0;     border-radius: 0;   width: 125px;   height: 22px;   position: relative;     z-index: 10;    font-size: 13px;    color: #ffffff; }

table th {  text-align: center;     background-color: #006fc4;  border: 1px solid #006fc4;  color: #fff;    width: 128px;   height: 22px; } 

table td {  text-align: center;     border: 1px solid #006fc4;  padding: 2px 2px;   width: 128px;   height: 22px; } 

ul { list-style-type: none; } input { text-align: center; width: 125px; height: 22px; font-size: 13px; }
```

Comment: You will need to go through some tutorial on [DOM manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone commented on your post, try and go through some tutorials about **DOM Manipulation**, but since he told you were to learn it, I'll give you the code to do this, and you can learn the rest later.

The easiest method to do what you want is just to insert a HTML tag in the code.

The first thing you should go ahead and do is make a variable with the div you need to insert/copy

```
var div = "<option value='1' selected='selected'>Monday</option>"
```

Now you have to insert the div somewhere.

```
document.getElementById("dls").innerHTML += div;
```

The code above inserts the HTML code you placed in the variable "div" into the element with the id of "dls".

Now obviously you don't just want to insert a bunch of divs with the text "Monday" and value="1"

So were going to make this more customizable...

First make we'll be making a function:

```
function insertNew(value, day) {

}
```

Now you have a function named insertNew() with two arguments, named value and day, so you can change it to insertNew(2, "Tuesday") but right now it does nothing no matter what, so we'll add a bit of code to the function.

First we'll be making a let variable in the function, so delete the original "div" variable, the difference between "var" and "let" is let only exists in that function and will be deleted after the function is done, it has a few more attributes but that's all you gotta worry about right now, but to be able to make the function easier to use we'll be making it more automatic.

```
function insertNew(value, day) {
    let div = "<option value='" + value + "' selected='selected'>" + day + "</option>";

    return div; // Return only spits the value out to the console, much like console.log(), but return stops the function from doing anymore code.
}
```

Now if you were to do insertNew(3, "Wednesday"), you'd get

```
<option value='3' selected='selected'>Wednesday</option>
```

So now you can then make it insert the code as well.

```
function insertNew(value, day) {
    let div = "<option value='" + value + "' selected='selected'>" + day + "</option>";

    document.getElementById("dls").innerHTML += div;
}
```

And it would insert with the right content, but to make the number automatically be filled out, you will have to create a variable outside the function, then every time the function has run increase the value of that function, and when you run the function instead of typing a number into the "value" argument of the function, simply type the name of the variable that counts up.

```
var number = 1;

function insertNew(value, day) {
    number++; // ++ just simply adds one to the integer much like number = number + 1, they do the same.

    let div = "<option value='" + value + "' selected='selected'>" + day + "</option>";

    document.getElementById("dls").innerHTML += div;
}
```

Now when you wanna run the function just run insertNew(number, "Tuesday") and every time you run it, the number will be increased by one, and if you really wanted to automate it, you could also add all the names of the days to an array and then cycle through it, and therefore only have to execute the function and not worry about changing anything...

**Hope this helps!**

*EDIT:* I noticed the script was inserting the wrong divs compared to what you wanted, but the code is adaptable just by changing the HTML in the variables, you can easily fix it!